# How to transform this XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make this XSL transformation consider only for siblings with the same id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183707/how-to-make-this-xsl-transformation-consider-only-for-siblings-with-the-same-id)

I have this input XML:

```
<map>
    <region>
        <gridA id="1">
            <blockA id="01" method="build">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="build">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>    

            <blockA id="01">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="modify"> 
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (prev node have same id but diff method so it's not considered as successive -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>    

            <blockA id="02">
                <building3 id="y" method="modify">
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building3>
                <building2 id="x" method="demolish"/>
            </blockA>      

            <blockA id="01">                
                <building1 id="y" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (diff id) -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>

            <blockA id="02">                
                <building3 id="y" method="modify"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building3>
                <building2 id="x" method="demolish"/> <!-- this one will be removed -->
            </blockA>          
        </gridA>   

        <gridA id="2">
            <blockA id="01" method="build">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="build">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (diff children) -->
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>                              
            <blockA id="01">                
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA> 
        </gridA>
        <gridB id="1">
            ...and so on..
        </gridB>
    </region>    
</map>
```

Expected Output:

```
<map>
    <region>
        <gridA id="1">
            <blockA id="01" method="build">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="build">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>    

            <blockA id="01">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="modify"> 
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (prev node have same id but diff method so it's not considered as successive -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>    

            <blockA id="02">
                <building3 id="y" method="modify">
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building3>
                <building2 id="x" method="demolish"/>
            </blockA>      

            <blockA id="01">                
                <building1 id="y" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (diff id) -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>

            <blockA id="02"/>                         
        </gridA>   

        <gridA id="2">
            <blockA id="01" method="build">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="build">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>

                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (diff children) -->
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>                              
            <blockA id="01"/>  
        </gridA>
        <gridB id="1">
            ...and so on..
        </gridB>
    </region>    
</map>
```

The XSLT so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/> <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="region/*/*/*
         [deep-equal(.,preceding::*[name()=current()/name()]
                       [@id = current()/@id]
                       [../../@id = current()/../../@id][1])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the problem with the XSLT right now is that it cannot differentiate duplicates that happens in siblings (i.e blockA with the same id).

I need to remove a node that are considered as *repetitive*.

**Two node that have the same `name` and `id` will be considered *repetitive* if it appears one after another and it has the same `method` and `children`.**

**for example:**

```
<elem id="1" method="a" />
<elem id="1" method="a" /> <!-- this is repetitive for id=1-->
<elem id="1" method="b" /> 
<elem id="1" method="a" /> <!-- this is the new boundary for removal id=1-->
<elem id="2" method="a" /> 
<elem id="1" method="a" /> <!-- this is repetitive for id=1 -->
<elem id="2" method="a" /> <!-- this is repetitive for id=2 -->
```

**will be simplified into:**

```
<elem id="1" method="a" />
<elem id="1" method="b" />
<elem id="1" method="a" /> <!-- this is the new boundary for removal id=1-->
<elem id="2" method="a" />
```

**- Everytime a successive node with the `same id` has `different method`, 
   the `boundary` for the next removal for that `id` is reset.**

- we need to take into account duplicates that are under one parent or siblings (two or more parents nodes that has the same element name and id) i.e (in example: `blockX`)
- if the two nodes being compared did not share the same `gridX` level, then they should not be considered as duplicates to be removed
- all of the subsequent duplicates will be removed until it becomes not duplicate: please see last part of the example with comment `<!-- this is the new boundary for removal id=1-->` although it has `elem id=1 method=a` it's not removed because the previous node is `elem id=1 method=b` which makes it as a non duplicate node.
- So the key is looking into successive node with same id first and then check if the method and the children are the same.

I'm sorry i don't know how to explain this in a more understandable sentence.

I hope the explanation is clear enough and not confusing.

Please let me know how to achieve such transformation using XSLT.
Thanks very much for the help.

John

Comment: Have you tried using the `preceding-sibling` axis from XPath and the `current()` function from XSLT?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, else it comes across a little as "please do my homework" :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I have used the preceding. Please have a look at the xslt. Thanks

Comment: @John replace "preceding" with "preceding-sibling"

Comment: @Utkanos I have updated my question with the xslt. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I have added more brief explanation. I hope it helps. Thanks very much.

Comment: @John - under your "for example" heading, I don't understand why the bottom two nodes are candidates for removal, at least according to the logic you describe. Neither of them *directly follows* a node with identical `id` and `method` (in each case, there is another node separating them from the previous identical node).

Comment: @Utkanos My mistake, I shouldn't put the word directly in there. Sorry.

Comment: @John - OK, but the logic still says the nodes are duplicates only if they appear one after the other (this still implies directly). So does this now mean nodes are duplicates if they have the same `id`, `method` and child nodes, with no emphasis on position? In other words, keep only the first of each kind, no subsequent duplicates?

Comment: @Utkanos Correct, but.. the tricky part is this: all of the subsequent duplicates will be removed *until* it becomes not duplicate: please see last part of the example with comment `<!-- this is the new boundary for removal id=1-->` although it has `elem id=1 method=a` it's not removed because the previous node is `elem id=1 method=b` which makes it as a non duplicate node. So the key is looking into successive node with same id first and then check if the method and the children are the same. I'm sorry i don't know how to explain this in a more understandable sentence. Hope u understand.

Comment: Sorry - I tried something but this one is just too complex.

Comment: @Utkanos that's OK. I really appreciate your time. :)