# How to make this XSL transformation consider only for siblings with the same id?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/> <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="region/*/*/*
         [deep-equal(.,preceding-sibling::*[name()=current()/name()]
                       [@id = current()/@id]
                       [../../@id = current()/../../@id][1])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So basically any subsequent duplicate (with same name, id, method and children) will be removed until it is **reset** (treated as unique or the first time it's found)

*The reset will happen if node with the same and id has different method.*

To make it clearer I have this simplified example as illustration:

```
<elem id="1" method="a" />
   <elem id="1" method="a" /> <!-- 1. this is duplicate -->
   <elem id="1" method="b" /> <!-- 2. this elem id=1 has different method, so it will be the reset point for elem id=1 -->
   <elem id="1" method="a" /> <!-- 3. this will be treated as unique because it's reset now so we don't remove this-->
   <elem id="2" method="a" /> <!--4.-->
   <elem id="1" method="a" /> <!-- this is repetitive for 3 and it willl be removed -->
   <elem id="2" method="a" /> <!-- this is repetitive for 4 so we remove this-->
and will be removed -->
```

**After transformation it will be simplified into:**

```
   <elem id="1" method="a" />
   <elem id="1" method="b" />
   <elem id="1" method="a" /> <!-- 3. this will be treated as unique because it's reset now so we don't remove this-->
   <elem id="2" method="a" />
```

So if it is applied to my XML input:

```
<map>
    <region>
        <gridA id="1">
            <blockA id="01" method="build">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="build">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>    

            <blockA id="01">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="modify"> <!-- this will be the reset point -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (prev node have same id but diff method so it's not considered as successive -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>    

            <blockA id="02">
                <building3 id="y" method="modify">
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building3>
                <building2 id="x" method="demolish"/>
            </blockA>      

            <blockA id="01">                
                <building1 id="y" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (diff id) -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>

            <blockA id="02">                
                <building3 id="y" method="modify"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building3>
                <building2 id="x" method="demolish"/> <!-- this one will be removed -->
            </blockA>          
        </gridA>   

        <gridA id="2">
            <blockA id="01" method="build">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="build">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (diff children) -->
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>                              
            <blockA id="01">                
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be removed -->
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA> 
        </gridA>
        <gridB id="1">
            ...and so on..
        </gridB>
    </region>    
</map>
```

Here is the expected output:

```
<map>
    <region>
        <gridA id="1">
            <blockA id="01" method="build">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="build">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>    

            <blockA id="01">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="modify"> <!-- this will be the reset point -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (prev node have same id but diff method) so it's not considered as successive -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>    

            <blockA id="02">
                <building3 id="y" method="modify">
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building3>
                <building2 id="x" method="demolish"/>
            </blockA>      

            <blockA id="01">                
                <building1 id="y" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (diff id) -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>

            <blockA id="02"/>        
        </gridA>   

        <gridA id="2">
            <blockA id="01" method="build">                 
                <building1 id="x" method="build">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </building1>

                <building1 id="x" method="build"> <!-- this one will be kept (diff children) -->
                    <otherchild>b</otherchild>
                </building1>
            </blockA>                              
            <blockA id="01"/>
        </gridA>
        <gridB id="1">
            ...and so on..
        </gridB>
    </region>    
</map>
```

Also if the two nodes being compared did not share the same 'gridA' level node, then they should not be considered as duplicates to be removed.

I've also considering to use

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($this-node/(preceding-sibling::* | ../preceding-sibling::*[@id = $this-node/parent::*/@id]/*)[name() = $this-node/name()][@id = $this-node/@id][deep-equal(*, $this-node/*)][@method = $this-node/@method]) mod 2 = 1"/>
```

as my resetting algorithm, but the first solution is better just need to tweak it to work on the siblings with same id. (from the example, it is: `<blockA id="xx">`) or if anyone has better solutions I would really like to know.

I hope anyone can enlighten me on this problem as this is very difficult for me to understand.

Thanks very much and apologize for the long questions.

Comment: I ran applied your current stylesheet against your provided sample and it perfectly meets your stated expected output. So as a use case, its worthless. I and others have talked to you about this before in relation to your almost identical other questions: YOU NEED GOOD USE/TEST CASES. The more complex your rules of transformation are, the more use cases you need to provide. At the very least you need at least one use case in which your current stylesheet does not work. Please revisit your question and provide a use case which your current stylesheet does not work as intended.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin please see my updated example which is more complex and showing where the stylesheet fails. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just needed to change the axis from preceding-sibling to preceding and test for the same 'gridA' level parent.

Try this ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/> <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="region/*/*/*
         [deep-equal(.,preceding::*   (: Note axis! Look back even past 'block' level :)
            [name()=name(current())]   (: Compare with same name :)
            [@id = current()/@id]      (: ... and same id :)
            [../.. is current()/../..] (: ... but only within the same 'gridA' level :)
            [1] (: Get the first predecessor that satisfies these conditions. :)
         )]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above solutions satisfies your posted use case.

---

## Update

I changed ...

```
  ../.. = current()/../..
```

... for ...

```
  ../.. is current()/../..
```

Comment: +1. I'm curious: how does `[../.. = current()/../..]` test equality? It looks to me like it is asking whether `../..` has the same *string value* (text content) as `current()/../..`. And as you may know, the string value is the concatenation of all descendants' text nodes' text content. This is not only inefficient, but could yield 'true' for two different `gridA` elements if they have the same string value. Since you're already using XPath 2.0, why not say `[../.. is current()/../..]`?

Comment: @Larsh, I believe that the "=" operator in 2.0, when operating on two sequences returns True iff the sequences are identical. I searched the XPath 2.0 spec, but I could not find any thing to either confirm or disprove my postulate. So I could be wrong. If I am wrong, and the = operator converts to string before comparison, as you say, could you point to a paragraph number in the spec which resolves this?  In any case, just in case, I have updated the answer to use the "is" operator, instead of "=". Thanks for that.

Comment: Using the `=` to compare two sequences will return `true` if any if the items in the first sequence are equal to any of the items in the second sequence.

Comment: @MadsHansen: Can you cite a reference for that?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans  If both objects to be compared are node-sets, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the first node-set and a node in the second node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the string-values of the two nodes is true.

Comment: @MadsHansen, Just to be clear the subject was the = operator under XSLT 2.0 . Your reference is for XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0. The relevant XPath 2.0 spec is http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20. The relevant section is either 3.5.2 or 3.5.3 - I can't work out which applies in this case.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: regarding your last comment, section 3.5.2 "General Comparisons" applies, because we are using the `=` operator. If you look at the beginning of section 3.5, it says that 3.5.3 "Node Comparisons" only applies to the operators `is`, `<<`, and `>>`.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: regarding your first comment above: I find the XPath 2.0 spec impenetrable in 3.5.2. Frankly I don't understand atomization; the "typed value" of an element node or node-set seems complex. I just go with the XPath 1.0 spec (which Mads quoted). The XPath 2.0 behavior seems to be backwards-compatible, when comparing node-sets.